# How to create schema for RDS from cloudformation template while launching the database?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, database-schema

I'm trying to install MYSQL (RDS) from cloud formation template. Is there a way to run SQL DDL script so we can create a schema at the time of database setup

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself ? Do you have expected out put?  Whats are you using to set up the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your infrastructure code(no matter it is CloudFormation or CDK, etc) should only care about provision the resources in the cloud, and nothing else.

The schema creation can be done after the database is launched, through AWS CodeBuild(I use flyway to do that https://flywaydb.org/).

What I did is:

1. I have a CDK package to create the infrastructure, where my RDS is provisioned. This package only cares about infrastructure, and nothing else.
2. I have a separate CDK package, which aims to perform schema migration only. This pipeline track my schema repository, and consists of CodeBuild where flyway can run to migrate schema(including schema initialization). The first time the CodeBuild run will initialize the database with the defined schema, once a new schema change is made and code submitted to the repository, the pipeline will get triggered, and build a new docker image with the new schema, and run the new docker image against the database to update schema. The database credential can be fetched from secret-manager as environment variables in CodeBuild.

The pipeline looks like this:

```
SourceStage => Docker Build Stage(using CodeBuild to build a docker image with the new schema) => Flyway Stage(using CodeBuild to run the docker image)
```

*Of course, you can merge above two packages into one package, as long as you separate code well to know that one part is for infrastructure only, and one is for database schema migration pipeline.*

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do this natively in CloudFormation. You'll have to have a script run after the template has been deployed that will run the DDL